# how i can reply to outlook email using python for the same sender by using below code?

Tags: email, python-3.5, pywin32, win32com, outlook-2016

I am trying to reply outlook email as we do manually it goes with previous conversations. But Below code is giving some error : Failed to send to the recipient address..I need to know how i can send it back to the person who sent me email..

```
import win32com.client, datetime
from datetime import timedelta    

outlook =win32com.client.Dispatch("Outlook.Application").GetNamespace("MAPI") # to trigger outlook application
inbox = outlook.GetDefaultFolder(6) # 6 is used for the index of the folder
messages = inbox.Items  
message = messages.GetLast()# message is treated as each mail in for loop 
for message in messages:                                          
    if message.Subject=="request": # based on the subject replying to email
        #body_content = message.body  
        message.Reply()  
        message.Body = "shortly will be processed!!!"  
        message.Send()
```

Answer (score 0):

The reply is a MailItem returned by reply().  So try this:

```
reply = message.Reply() 
reply.Body = "shortly will be processed!!!" 
reply.Send()
```

Comment: Thanks it worked without any error but It's replying without reflecting previous conversations i mean, Replied message should attach with the mail i received before replying.

Comment: I've never seen outlook do this by hitting reply so the COM side wouldn't either. Unless you mean that the text of the original email should appear in the reply.  You have the original message so you can easily add it to the reply as an attachment, or copy its text and header info into the email. Either way this goes beyond the original question so you should mark this as answered, try what I suggested and post a new question if you can't get what you want.

Answer (score 0):

continuing to above answer

to reply all:

```
`rplyall=message.ReplyAll()`
```

to reflect previous conversations:

```
`rplyall.Body="your message here"+rplyall.Body()`

`rplyall.Send()`
```

Answer (score 0):

Since MailItem.Body is a String and it is not callable. [Reference document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.mailitem.body)
I think the correct code in @Akhil 's answer is

```
    rplyall.Body = "your message here" + rplyall.Body
    rplyall.Send()
```